# ASP.NET Core get generated FB link through ControllerBase.Challenge()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am currently working with External Authentication (Facebook) using ASP.NET core MVC and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` library. The authentication managed by ActionController, all returning response are reflecting to razor view. Problem is, An action method deal with fb login, which is actually generating fb login url using my fb app id, secret key etc and redirecting to the generated fb link. i need to get the generated link in **server side**, there is no way i have found to get the link, because the response type is `ControllerBase.Challenge()` , i hope you'll understand the context if you see my below codes:

**ASP.NET Core MVC Controller:**

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Account", new { returnUrl });
        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }
}
```